# How can I relate a ID to an actual name in a Database

Tags: database, relation

I have a database but one part of it that has baffled me is how I can get it to relate a supplier ID to the name of the supplier.

So for example I want to add a product through a form but at the moment when I come to select supplier ID it will only show the ID number (5, for example), rather than the name of the supplier the ID relates to

Comment: In DB world, you always operate with ID's, while showing to user some other ID-associated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you need to do is join the supplier table with the product table.  Assuming the product table has a supplier_id column, something like this:

(**EDIT** based on first comment)

```
SELECT p.description, s.supplierId, s.supplierName
FROM product p
INNER JOIN supplier s ON s.supplierId = p.supplierId
WHERE p.id = some_value;
```

If you post the table descriptions, like a SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name, this could be refined and made more useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have only supplierId and supplierName in the suppliers table.

Comment: Edited a bit to reflect the column names you supplied.  Is this what you are looking for?  If not, supply DDL or some other description of the tables' structure.

Comment: thanks, I beleive i got it to work from the first one you posted. Maybe i could extend this and relate the products with who supplies what? Any ideas on how to go about this? I beleive I would just need to manipulate the query already done

Comment: If this worked for you, perhaps you could upvote it/accept it as the answer.  For the new query...you want a list of all suppliers, and the products they supply?  Just remove the WHERE clause and change INNER JOIN to RIGHT JOIN.  That will list all the suppliers, and the products they supply, or NULL for p.description if they don't supply any products.